# Incremental learning for Support Vector Machines Classification

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am currently trying to find a good implementation for the Cawenbergs and Poggio’s algorithm for incremental and decremental SVM. I have found this one: [Incremental-SVM-Learning-in-MATLAB](https://github.com/diehl/Incremental-SVM-Learning-in-MATLAB/tree/master), but I don't really understand how the algorithm is implemented in the MatLab code.

I have tried to analyse it deeply and study it but still no success on understanding it. I am looking for some help to understand the code or even other solutions with a clearer implementation.

Any help is very welcome, you would do me a huge favor!

Here is the algorithm I am currently focused on:

[The Cawenbergs and Poggio’s algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcJpz.png)

Comment: Where did you exactly get stuck? Could you share your attempt?  Could you share a minimal example so that others can help you? Have you tried asking chatgpt for an initial version? :)

Comment: @DanielPerezEfremova Unfortunately, for now I am just trying to understand the code from the link I provided. And yes, I have asked chatgpt but was not much help :( Indeed I'll post the algorithm I am working with.